# Selenium element not clickable. Message: move target out of bounds (Session info: chrome=77.0.3865.90)

Tags: python-3.x, selenium-webdriver

when ever i tried to click element i get the error Message: move target out of bounds (Session info: chrome=77.0.3865.90). I tied using the simpler way as well as using the action chains but no luck, can any one point out where the problem is. NOTE: XPATH to to the element is correct as well as when i use the action chains correct element is in focus, but still element do not get clicked.

Here is the Code:

```
showMore=WebDriverWait(driver, 5).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//a[@id='seeMore']//*[@class='icon arrow-down-light ']")))
actions = ActionChains(driver)
actions.move_to_element(showMore)
actions.perform()
time.sleep(5)
showMore.click()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Trying using offset

actions.move_to_element_with_offset(showMore, 5, 5)

Comment: Thanks for the answer, can you please explain a bit, what the problem is?

Comment: the problem is the element you want to click or perform are not visible on the screen maybe the element is present in up page or down page so to view that element you need to scroll down or up that's what we do we move to the element where that s present and then click or perform

Comment: i used action chains to reach and focus on to the element, but the same result.

Comment: Have you used action chains move to element with offset ??

Comment: no, i have not used the offset, i tried focusing and reaching using the action chains, i don't understand  why it can reach and focus using the action chains but can not click it i am not been able to understand the concept of using an offset can you please explain a bit.